# Is there a writable iterator in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, mutable

In C+ one can use iterators for writing to a sequence. Simplest example would be:

```
vector<int> v;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
    *it = 42;
}
```

I need something more complicated - keep iterator as a class member for a later use.
But I don't know how to get this behavior from Java iterators.

Are there writable iterators in Java at all?
If not then what replaces them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`ListIterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) (which you can obtain by [`List#listIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29)) has [`add()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29) and [`set()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set%28E%29) methods which allows you to respectively insert and replace the item at the currently iterated index. That's as far the only "writable iterator" as I can think of in Java.

<sub>Not sure though if that is the exact replacement of the given C++ code since I don't know C++.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything like that for arrays ?

Comment: @Lukasz: You can turn an array into a List (in constant time) with `Arrays.asList` and then get a ListIterator from that.

Comment: No, you should prefer `List` over array. The `List` is the Java abstraction of an array and you can use `ArrayList` to have a dynamically expandable array. To learn more about `List` (which is part of Java Collections API), check [the Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: An ArrayList is a dynamically expansible array. A List could be anything (anything that adheres to the interface, that is).

Answer (score 2):

As arrays can be accessed directly and quickly by their index, you don't really need an iterator object. Wouldn't it be enought to save the index of the array in that class member? This would permit to read and write the value of the array.

PS: You could use an ArrayList, which is an automatically growing set of arrays and use the ListIterator as Balus described in order to use the iterator-object-approach.

Comment: To set a value int won't be enough. I need both int and array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like you want a `List` (or maybe some other collection, like `Set`) or an array.

Also, you could just make your contents mutable.  It looks silly for integers, but continuing your example

```
for (MutableInteger i : CollectionOfMInts) i.setTo(42);
```